# How can I prevent the iCloud dialog from showing up for new users?

Tags: icloud, user-account, macos

On 10.7.2, whenever a new account is created, and the person logs in for the first time, they see the iCloud system pref pane.

Is there a way to prevent this from showing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a `Terminal` window:

> `sudo defaults write /System/Library/User\Template/Non_localized/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE`

[Source](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/disabling-the-icloud-sign-in-pop-up-message/)

Comment: I think that needs a slash in front of System:
    defaults write /System/Library (etc)