# Setting defaults for Magic Mouse

Tags: macos, user-account, defaults, mouse

When I log on the Guest user, the Magic Mouse settings are not as I want them to be. E.g., I would always like the right click enabled and the tracking speed set to fast, but these settings default to unwanted values. So every time after login on Guest, I must change these settings manually.

Is there a way to change the defaults setting for the Magic Mouse so that every new user will get these changed defaults ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process. The system make all new accounts from this template:

```
/System/Library/User Template
```

Unless you need to only change a specific localization, you'll be putting files into `/System/Library/User Template/Non_localized/Library/Preferences`

The two step process is knowing where to change a file and what change to make.

I don't have an answer to the second part (no Magic Mouse handy), but you might be able to do that part yourself. If you make a new account and change only that mouse preference and dig through the ~/Library/Preferences to isolate the file(s) that encode that change (sort them by date and the newest files should be the ones you changed to configure the mouse). Second, you need to copy that file into the default user template so that when the system makes a new account (guest account or any new account), that user gets the modified mouse settings you have copied into the template to replace the default values for that setting.

An alternate method is to look inside the file(s) to see if the settings can be written easily by a `sudo defaults` command:

- [How can I prevent the iCloud dialog from showing up for new users?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28602/how-can-i-prevent-the-icloud-dialog-from-showing-up-for-new-users)

Answer (score -2):

First of all you may need to unhide the hiden files so open terminal and run those commands :

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

killall Finder
```

To switch back, do the same but substitute FALSE for TRUE.

Now 
Login to your guest account, there set chrome as your default browser (or even Firefox) 
Then do not logout ! This would erase your session, so use the  on the top right corner use the swich user drop down menue, 
Now that you are back again in your Admin account,
Find the new temporary guest home folder, under

```
 Users/Guest
```

Select all the folders inside of it,
And copy them in :

```
 /System/Library/User Template/English.lproj/
```

English or whatever your languish is if you are using your computer in french this should be :

```
  /System/Library/User Template/French.lproj/
```

as you can see in this folder there was the defaults folders for the guest account 
By modifying them you have just modified default appearance of the guest user account
You may want to save this folder in a safe place before, in case you want to undo your work.

For reference , 
You just have to follow the steps as shown in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU-W2-_c5bA

Or if you prefer text version :

http://www.michaelsmac.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=394